# When will a servlet container interrupt my thread?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm writing a servlet, which is executed in Java servlet container (eg, JBoss, Jetty, Tomcat, GlassFish).

What are the reasons for a servlet container to interrupt the thread running my HTTP request handler? Will it do that only when shutting down? Will it do that when the client is not responding?

Is it standardized, or is any container free to do what he wishes?

To clarify, I'm not talking about interrupting new threads that I create, only on the servlet container's threads my requests are running on. (Although it'll be interesting if you'll mention what happens to new threads in the answer).

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, when you said "thread", do you *actually* mean "HTTP request"?

Comment: Well, technically it will interrupt my thread, and it will happen when the thread happens to run my HTTP request. So I'm not sure how to write it. Rephrased that, hope it's better.

Comment: The scenarios are very different if you spawn threads on your own. So you need to be more clear what thread exactly you mean and how it's been created and if it's a daemon thread or not, etcetera.

Comment: @BalusC, sorry. No I never spawn a thread of my own. I'll clarify it in the question. I guess that if I'm spawning a thread, there's no reason he'll call interrupt about it (how will it know it exists?).

Comment: So, after all, you *actually* mean the "HTTP request"? (which is at its own served in a single thread which is managed by the container itself)

Comment: Yes. I thought I clarified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What are the reasons for a servlet container to interrupt the thread running my HTTP request handler?*

That depends on the container itself. It's indeed not standardized in the servlet specification.

> *Will it do that only when shutting down?*

Seems one of the most obvious reasons. Local tests taught me that at least Tomcat 7.0.22 and Glassfish 3.1.1 will abort all the servlet's processing immediately without letting them to continue their task. No exceptions will be thrown at that point.

> *Will it do that when the client is not responding?*

Only when the request headers are not fully arrived. There's a container-specific timeout on the socket connection which is usually 60 seconds. But if the request headers are not fully arrived, then your servlet method won't be entered anyway. Only if the request headers are fully arrived, then your servlet method will be entered.

Then, inside the servlet method; if the client has supplied a request body (e.g. POST) and your servlet's code starts reading the request body by for example `request.getParameter()` or `request.getInputStream()`, then it will throw `IOException` when the client has aborted sending the request body at that point. On the other hand, when you write to the response (and flush/commit it), then also an `IOException` will be thrown when the client aborts the connection at that point. You can if necessary put it in a `try-catch`, but you can't do anything more with it than just logging. The usefulness of those loggings is highly quesitonable and will likely only clutter your server logs.

Comment: So basically, I can ignore `InterruptedException` in the servlet code, as it should never happen?

Comment: Yes. Even more, you can only catch it if you're creating and managing the threads *yourself*.

Comment: I can catch it for instance with `process.waitFor()` which throws it.

Comment: That's just a thread which you spawned yourself and you thus have to manage yourself. Which is a pretty bad idea though on a lifelong running Java EE web application. Also, every `Runtime#exec()` you're doing will create a new JVM runtime context which allocates **as many memory as** the currently running webserver JVM. Be warned for out of memory problems when multiple visitors do this simultaneously... I'd rethink this approach. Port it to Java or use JNI/JNA or maybe RMI.

Comment: (yes, but I created this thread implicitly) WHAT?! Isn't there any portable sane Java way to execute another process? Is Java one of those selfish creatures that you either take entirely, or never use? I can't port third parties binaries to Java you know... Can't it use vfork to execute the process? (Thanks for the very important tip)

Comment: With such construct, JNI/JNA is definitely your best bet. Write a small C(++) program which executes the 3rd party CLI program and then let your webapp use JNI/JNA to execute that C program.